# Pass Firebase automatically collected user properties to Google Tag Manager

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I would like to pass the automatically collected Device Model user property from Firebase Analytics to Google Tag Manager so that I can attach it to events and send it to Google Analytics as a session-scoped custom dimension (as Google Analytics does not capture device model for iOS by default, like it does with Android).

You can see the full list of automatically collected user properties here:

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486?hl=en&ref_topic=6317484

I can see Device Model when I run queries in BigQuery (which is connected to our Firebase console), but what I want to know is what the internal name is for the Device Model user property.

What I plan to do is to create a custom user property variable in GTM and set the User Property Key Name, but I can't find anything online that would indicate what it is. Does anyone know what it is for this property?

Comment: I don't have an answer for your question but I have a question if you mind: Have you please an idea about if multiple userProperty values (of the same userProperty key) can be associated to the same user (device)?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can - I am assuming you mean if a user were to make multiple purchases, could you pass each item to the same user property? We use user properties primarily for things like setting an id, for booleans (i.e. if users have activated certain features or not) and for recurring usage characteristics.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And what about the frequency of values update? Is it possible to edit the value each hour for example?

Comment: That's not limited at all, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer to this came from a Google engineer who answered via our Account Manager (we are a GA 360 customer): the short answer is this information is not captured in a way that can be passed automatically via GTM, so if you want to send this information to Google Analytics you need to manually capture it and then send it as either a user property or a parameter.